# QGIS buffer does not work on few features in the same multiline layer

Tags: qgis, line, buffer

I am trying to use QGIS buffer to do buffering around a MultiLine layer. While the command generally works well, I can not get a buffer for few features in the same layer. I wonder what causes the problem since it only does not work for just a few features.

[image]

As it can be seen from the picture, the buffer commend does not work for the red MultiLine, while it works for other features (with a green buffer).

Comment: try to check/repair the geometry as geometry error may cause problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @J.R I've already checked geometry. Everything is fine and there is no problem with the geometry!

Comment: The buffer commend does not work for few features within the same layer.

Comment: You should provide your data for testing. Otherwise, we can just start to speculate. Maybe the red line is not on the same layer?

Comment: Do the other buffer tools in QGIS fail similarly?  GDAL, GRASS & SAGA have such a tool.  If you copy your layer to a new project and try the buffer tool there does that work?

Comment: @johns, thanks for the tip. The buffer tool in Grass works for all features and the GDAL buffer does not buffer all features. My issue is solved, however I wonder what might cause such a problem?!